# Memory management in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

I have done one project in corona sdk for iPad and android,in that four main modules are there,and one module also has some sub modules.for changing the scenes I used director class.
Eventhough I followed every memory management techniques,my project is quiting within 15 minutes,is there any solution for this?thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried solutions from [memory leak prevention](http://alias-www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/08/15/corona-sdk-memory-leak-prevention-101/) article? You can display/log current memory usage and try to find what is allocating the memory. That plus additional debugging would help you find where the problem actually is and what is allocating the memory.

After location of the problem is known you need to determine why the memory is not freed. E.g. make sure you're correctly removing objects from the scene:

```
display.remove( redBall )
redBall = nil
```

See also the discussion on Corona SDK forum:

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/3637-how-do-i-tell-if-my-game-is-leaking/

Comment: Both the links above are broken.

Comment: I updated the links with new domain (coronalabs.com)